# Toolkit for easy and common tasks for developers

Tags: c#, developer-tools, toolkit

I always used tools online for different actions, like encode, decode, pretty print for example json, xml. I'm looking for a tool that has all of that in 1 site or even something that can install or have in my pc.

Thanks for the recommendations.

use different websites

Comment: Please add way more details to your question. Encode/Decode what? Pretty Print what? Your question is very unspecific.

Please clarify your question.

Also since you are rather new to StackOverflow please read this tutorial on how to properly ask a question on StackOverflow: [The Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

I created [CodersToolkit](https://coderstoolkit.com) a while ago. My motivation behind it was to have all needed tools in the same place, a nice UI, and that my changes would be persisted next time I got in (So that I wouldn't lose them).
I hope you like it. I'll be adding more tools.